# Why text input field in IE 8 is always 6px wider than the other browser?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, debugging, input

**Update:** I think it is because of IE box-model problem. But, it kind of confusing that the debugger shows the "content-width" 156px as well as height 22px:

[image]

If I set boarder and padding to 0, the content-width is correct, which is 150px:

[image]

Here comes the problem, it seems like, if I set the boarder and padding, the total width of the whole width in IE will become 156px + 6px; In Chrome/Firefox it is 150px + 6px;

If I clear the boarder and padding, the total width becomes:
IE: 150px + 0, Chrome/Firefox: 150px + 0;

I used style="width: 150px;" to set width of the a text input field. It works perfectly in Chrome/Firefox, but always 6px wider in IE8/10. I used IE debugger to check the width of the text input field. If I set the width to 146px, then the width becomes 150px.

I tried to set "box-sizing" to "content-box" as well set up the fonts. They didn't help at all.

Right now, my only solution is write a specific width for IE. Is there anyway to solve this issue? Thanks!!

Comment: Please confirm whether the browser is in standards mode. This sounds like a Quirks mode issue. I can't tell for sure without seeing any code, but if that's the problem, then the solution is easy: get out of quirks mode.

Comment: try resets.. or help with fiddle.

Comment: @Spudley Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "Quirks mode".

Comment: @DavidLiu: Quirks mode is an old rendering mode that exists in some browsers and gets activated if your page doesn't have a valid doctype. It causes a lot of layout issues like the ones you're describing, and also switches off a lot of browser features. You might want to [read my blog post on the topic](http://spudley.com/blog/keeping-ie-in-standards-mode)

Comment: @Spudley Thanks, my doctype declaration is <!DOCTYPE html>, I assume this is a valid HTML 5 doctype declaration.

Comment: @DavidLiu - yes, that is the correct doctype. You should still check the mode (by pressing F12; the mode info is displayed in the dev tools window), because other things can trigger quirks mode. But in general the doctype is the main culprit. Tell us what mode is shown in dev tools; if it's quirks mode, then there are a few other tips to check (keep reading the blog). If it isn't, then we will definitely need to see the code you're having trouble with in action in order to help any futher.

Comment: @Spudley How can I tell if it is in "Quirks mode" or not in the dev tools?

Comment: @Spudley It is "IE8 standards", which I set it to using X-UA-Compatible".

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with the IE box model

[image]

Thus if you have padding or border it could mess it up but that's just my guess.

Comment: The "IE box model" you refer to is the box model in Quirks mode. If you have IE in standards mode (which you should always try to do) then it uses the same standard box model as all the other browsers.

Comment: @Spudley I think right now, my IE behaviors like it in "Quirks mode", please refer to my screenshot.